# I want to return the top 3 best doing stocks for a selected time period using alphavantage API. is this possible?

Tags: python, api, alpha-vantage

I'm working on some project and I would like to make a method that shows the top 3 best doing stocks. However when going through the alphaavantage documentation I don't see a possibility to get all the stocks their information without have to ask them separately with their tokens/symbols.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Thank you